# How to save html form and send via ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

how can i save a form with different values in an array every time when i click the button save. After that when i'm finished with the orders I click the button send a the whole array with the stored information is sending via ajax to php.

it should look like this `var order = [fname: .... , lname: ..., 1.order:{product:p1, color:c3}, 2.order:{product:p3, color:c2}, 3.order... and so one]`
is this even possible to do it this way or is there a better solution for that ? I don't have the possibility to connect to mysql

here is my example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4acj5wab/
my problem is evertime i'm pushing the new value it overrides me the old one.

```
<form action="">
  fname:<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
  lname:<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
  <select name="selectProduct"><br>
    <option value="p1">product1</option>
    <option value="p2">product2</option>
    <option value="p3">product3</option>
  </select><br>
  <select name="selectColor"><br>
    <option value="c1">color1</option>
    <option value="c2">color2</option>
    <option value="c3">color3</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button type="button" id="saveAndOrder" name="saveAndOrder" >Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="sendOrder" name="sendOrder" >Send</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var order = []
$('#saveAndOrder').on('click', function(){
    var myData = $('form').serializeArray();
  order.push(myData);
});

$('#sendOrder').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'myphp.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: order,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html('Thank you...');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: "everytime i push the new value it overrides the old one". I don't see this happening. Look at https://jsfiddle.net/4acj5wab/2/ - I added a log to display the contents of order. I you press Save twice, and then press Send, your array contains two elements (each of which is itself an array)

Comment: yes its working now. strange. is it possible to show just the name and values of each input or select element ?

Comment: were you forgetting to press Save the 2nd time by any chance? Maybe your UI needs a rethink. It's very easy for the the most recently entered item not to get submitted if the user forgets to press Save before Send.

Comment: if the user click send without clicking the save button that it sholud send me the current form. i can catch the order len and decide what to do

Comment: it doesn't though because you don't serialise the current form within the sendOrder function. It's only serialised if you click Save. But if you start causing it to serialise the current form within Send, then if the user had also clicked Save it will send that set of values twice (see the answer below which has exactly that problem). You should have just the Save button on the form, then a list below it showing the user what they have saved, and below that list a Send button so it's clear they are sending all the items. Also, reset the form every time they click Save.

Answer (score 0):

try something like thing keep it as seperate forms and serialize and send them i didnt check on code please verify

html

```
<form action="" id="form1">
  fname:<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
  lname:<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
  </form>
<form action="" id="form2">  
  <select name="selectProduct"><br>
    <option value="p1">product1</option>
    <option value="p2">product2</option>
    <option value="p3">product3</option>
  </select><br>
  <select name="selectColor"><br>
    <option value="c1">color1</option>
    <option value="c2">color2</option>
    <option value="c3">color3</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button type="button" id="saveAndOrder" name="saveAndOrder" >Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="sendOrder" name="sendOrder" >Send</button>
  </form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript

```
var order = []
$('#saveAndOrder').on('click', function(){
alert("save");
    var myData = $('form2').serializeArray();
  order.push(myData);
});

$('#sendOrder').on('click', function(){
var myData = $('form1').serializeArray();
var data = []
data.push(myData);
data.push(order);
alert(data);
    $.ajax({
    url: 'myphp.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html('Thank you...');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: if the user presses Save and then immediately Send it will submit the most recently entered item twice. OTOH the original meant that if you forget to press Save before Send then the most recently entered item is not submitted at all. UI possibly needs a bit of a rethink.

Comment: keep a boolean variable to see if the user has save if not you can call both functions

Comment: that would work, although personally I think the UI is unclear and not user-friendly. In the main comments above I suggested to OP what a user-friendly UI might look like.